# How to copy a specific file in a folder using terminal

Tags: linux, command

I am using terminal on linux. I am in my current folder now. I want to take a file in this folder that I am currently in and copy it in the exact same folder and I also want to rename it.

What command should I use?

Comment: For more information on how to use the `cp` command, look at `cp`'s man page (short for manual). You can see the man page with the command `man cp`.

Comment: remember to google and look at _manpages_ next time - [`man cp`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/cp1.html)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about copying a specific file in a folder to another file using terminal.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Copy command works well.

```
cp /currentfolder/filename /currentfolder/newfilename
```

Answer (score 4):

If you wanna copy a file like .cpp file it is really easy to use:

```
cp filename.cpp destination
```

Comment: The question also asked about renaming.